# Error Loading Crystal Report in Client Machine

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I have developed a windows application using vs2010 c# and also generated crystal report using the application.The problem is I am able to view report on my computer but when the same application runs on a client machine its throwing an error

> "could not load file or assembly crystaldecisions.windows.forms version 13.0"

I am not able to load the report on client machine. What could be the possible reasons for the error.

Answer (score 1):

Include the dll crystaldecisions.windows.forms in the deploy to the client machine. Usually you can just mark the file in solution explorer to copy local, and then deploy the bin folder in you installer.

Comment: If it worked, please mark my reply as the answer. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean again, did it work and is now broken again, or did this not work at all?

Comment: Tried in a system which has crystal report installed previously.Didnt notice that.

Comment: Yes that's because the dll is more than likely loaded into the GAC.  You need to either load the dll into the GAC or include it in your applications running directory

Comment: how to load the dll in GAC or in application running directory

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the crystal report viewer to the client machine.
note you have to make sure that it is the same version that on your machine, you can check the version from the

```
     web.config
```

file that you have, something like this

```
 <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
```

for  install CRV for VS 2010 : 
http://global.sap.com/campaign/ne/free_trial/crystal_reports_visual_studio/wty_int_crvs.epx

Comment: Is there any possibility to view crystal report without installing crystal report in client machine??

Comment: Not all crystal report (Developer tool) only the viewer.